# Source that Og told Sarah about the Akeidah, and thus she died

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, binding-of-isaac, sarah, og

Someone recently told me that they were taught as a child that Og was the one who told Sarah about the Akeidah, causing her death. I always understood it as the *Satan*. Indeed, that's what **Midrash Tanchuma** [*Vayeira* § 23](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Vayera.23.5?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and one version of **Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer** (Chapter 32, Zichron Aharon ed.) say ([Rashi to Genesis 23:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.23.2?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.23.2.3&lang2=he&w2=all&lang3=he) brings similarly, although he doesn't mention the *Satan*).

I looked all over and found no version of the *Midrash* that says it was Og, and assumed this person was mistaken. Then I found on Otzar HaChochmah the *sefer* **Kuntres Be'er HaMegillah**, [which says](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=197336&width=-17&scroll=0&pagenum=5) that *Chazal* tell us that Og was the one who informed Sarah.

Now, either this *sefer* is also mistaken, or there's some *Midrash* that I can't find. Where, if anywhere, does it say that Og told her about the Akeidah?

Comment: Pirkei d'rabbi Eliezer 32 has Samae"l. Perhaps it's a conflation with the Medrash about Og (*hapalit*) telling Avraham about Lot's capture (cited by Rashi on Gen. 14:13).

Comment: @Robev what text do you use to be able to check dozens of different midrashim by a certain question, like who told Sarah etc, in a short amount of time? I have not found any text in english that makes this a quick process, so wondering what your system is if you wouldnt mind sharing that.

Comment: @ShipBuilding well two things: 1) I don't look in English, I look at different Midrashim in their original Hebrew 2) who says it took a short amount of time? :-) I just spent thirty minutes looking into this question again and looked at 7 different versions of this *Midrash*. Torah Sheleimah is a resource I use a lot, although not in this case.

Comment: Wasn't Eliezer traditionally one of the the two extras Avraham took with him?   Can't do the whole Og=Eliezer thing if he was around for Sarah to ask.

Comment: @Nic some Midrashim equate Og with Eliezer, but I see no contradiction. After the Akeidah Og/Eliezer went and told Sarah...

Answer (score -3):

I suspect that the word עוג in Kuntress Be'er HaMegillah is a typo and should actually read as the abbreviation, עו״ג which means עובד גילולים, an idol worshipper. The [Pirkei d'Rabbi Eliezer 32:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.32.8?vhe=Pirkei_Derabi_Eliezer&lang=he) references a specific angel (the Angel of Death) that would have been working through some human agent. But it does not mention who that specific individual was by name.

But as a point of reference, [Sefer HaYashar says something exactly like this at the end of parshat Vayera](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30784&st=&pgnum=43) which says:

> הנה השטן בא אל שרה בדמות איש כו׳

Together with other sources it points out that Sarah left her home and went to the city of Chevron looking for Avraham and her son when she became worried at the time of the Akeidah.

Sarah did this because that is the original direction that Avraham indicated he would go when he departed for the Akeidah.

Chevron was at that time a Canaanite city called Kiryat Arba, named after its King and founder, Arba. Arba was the greatest of the Anakim, the giants who originally inhabited the land of Israel according to [Yehoshua 14:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.14.15?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and [15:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.15.13?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he). These were individuals who had followed the path of Enosh and his generation and the development of idol worship.

Og was another of those giants, who was the King of Bashan according to [Devarim 3:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.3.11?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).

Because they were related, this may have been the association with Og as the individual who told Sarah.

Comment: Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer says the Angel of Death was working through some agent? Or that last part is your suggestion. Since when does the Angel of Death work through human intervention?

Comment: @robev In general, angels influence what is already in place in the material world. That's how the system is set up. There are occasional exceptions mentioned in Torah to that rule. But not usually.

Comment: Shach Al Hatorah (http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=45690#p=26&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) says that she asked Achiman, Sheshai and Talmai, the giants in Chevron, and they said they saw Avraham and Yitzchak from afar, with Avraham about to sacrifice Yitzchak. So it could be that the author of the book in the OP confused them with Og (all of them being giants).

Comment: @Meir That's a good source, but I'm not sure who or what Achiman, Sheshai and Talmai are exactly. They, together with their 4th partner, Shalom, appear in several places in Tanach. They appear to be angelic influences in some contexts. If you read Shach carefully, they seem to be traveling with Samael and Sarah communicates with them prophetically.

Comment: Huh? In the 3 places in Tanach where they appear, they're giants who live in Chevron, and in 2 of those places it describes how the Jews dispossessed/killed them. There's no Shalom with them anywhere. (There is a Shallum together with Achiman in Divrei Hayamim, among the gatekeepers of the Beis Hamikdash, but that's obviously not the same Achiman, any more so than Chanoch the son of Kayin is identical with Chanoch the son of Reuven.) Nor does Shach associate them with Sa"m at all; he just says that Sarah didn't believe the Satan's report, so she went to AS&T to ask them to look.

Comment: @Meir Shach is emphasizing that Sarah is using her prophetic ability in this episode. When's the last time you had a conversation with the Angel of Death?

Comment: @Meir Some say they were descendants of Og.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, what makes you think she can't be first communicating with an angel and then with regular human beings? Lot did, to give but one example.

Comment: @user6591 Source for that? At the end of Chukas the Jews kill Og "and all of his children," but AS&T were killed only later, in Sefer Shoftim.

Comment: @meir I'm going to have to retract my statement. It was the nephilim mentioned in Shelach. As brought in Toras Chida. #37 from Pnei David in the name of Nimukei Rid. His vort was that the Moreh (?) said these nephilim were the children of Shamchazei and Azael who fell to earth. His question was they would've died in Mabul? He answered they were from the children of Og as it says he was from the remainder of the Repha'im. Ad kan divarav.

Comment: @user6591 Got it, and thanks for that source. Now that I think of it, actually, in Chukas it doesn't say that they killed "all of" Og's children, just "and his children" (ואת בניו), so maybe indeed AS&T could have been his children and survived that. Or maybe the Chida just means that other Nefilim that the Meraglim reported seeing were Og's children.